# Recursion stops after one branch search for implementation of the Spider in the Game Hive

Tags: java, recursion, depth-first-search

We are implementing the rules of the game called [Hive](https://www.gen42.com/download/rules/hive/Hive_English_Rules.pdf). In the game the Spider piece can only move three Hexagons.

We are trying to find a path using dfs, but the problem is that our dfs search stops after looking at one branch.

We tried to make use of depth - 1. So when the depth == 0 then it should go to the next branch. But it seems that something is wrong with the return statement.

What's wrong with this recursion?

```
public Set findPathForSpider(Game game, Point origin, Point destination, Point actualOrigin, Set<Point> hasVisited, int depth) throws Exception {
        if(origin.equals(destination)) {
            game.moveWithoutRestriction(destination.x, destination.y, actualOrigin.x, actualOrigin.y);
            return hasVisited;
        }

        if(depth == 0) {
            return new HashSet();
        }

        hasVisited.add(origin);

        for (Point emptyNeighbor : getEmptyNeighbors(game, origin)) {
            if (!hasVisited.contains(emptyNeighbor)) {
                if (!game.isHiveBrokenAfterPush(origin, emptyNeighbor)) {
                    hasVisited.add(emptyNeighbor);
                    game.moveWithoutRestriction(origin.x, origin.y, emptyNeighbor.x, emptyNeighbor.y);
                    return findPathForSpider(game, emptyNeighbor, destination, actualOrigin, hasVisited, depth - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return new HashSet();
    }
```

We call the findPathForSpider in the spiderRestrictions that is in a Game class. The recursion depth is 3

```
public boolean spiderRestrictions(Point originPoint, Point destinationPoint) throws Exception{
        Set path = b.findPathForSpider(this, originPoint, destinationPoint, originPoint, new HashSet<>(), 3);
        return !path.isEmpty() &&
                !originPoint.equals(destinationPoint) &&
                b.isHexagonEmpty(destinationPoint);
    }
```

Comment: please share how findPathForSpider from the calling method (as opposed to from itself)

Comment: @JeremyKahan Do you mean how we call the method?

Comment: yes. I'm wondering what depth goes in in the first place

Comment: It is 3. I just updated the post.

Comment: Thanks. So that was not it, except that it makes clear that when depth = 0 you're not going to the next branch. In  if(depth == 0) {
            return new HashSet();
        }
I would expect some kind of call on getSpider, I think. But I'm not certain, sorry.

Comment: Please post [mre]